# Is there a way to see the grid results expanded in LinqPad?

Tags: linqpad

LINQPad is great for quickly looking for results with its awesome "Dump" method.

However, when I am looking on a dictionary that holds an array (or an object), I see it like that:

[image]

To actually see the value in each row, I have to click "Value", which opens a new tab. I'd really like a way to see all the values expanded in one view.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it what I was looking for. I had to switch to "Results to rich text" (CTRL+SHIFT+T). However, at that view I still couldn't see the values properly:

[image]

However, that turned out to be because I did `.Dump(0)` instead of just `.Dump()`. Wit that fixed, I was able to expand the dictionary and see the whole picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is, but it requires some coding on your part.

You'll have to implement an extension for LINQPad, and in that extension implement the `ICustomMemberProvider` interface. You can just put this code right along in your assembly. If it is in the `LINQPad` namespace, LINQPad will pick it up and use it.

For more info, see the LINQPad FAQ at http://www.linqpad.net/FAQ.aspx